# Return to calling page after save button

Tags: redirection

I am putting together a simple restaurant menu function for a site. I have a menu content type imaginatively called 'restaurant menu item' I use for each dish. I have created a restauranter's "dashboard" for them to update their site including the menu. With views, I have created a table containing the full menu, a row for each dish and on each row there's an 'edit' and 'delete' button. Their function is pretty obvious I'm sure.

When the edit button is clicked, it goes to the (themed) edit content page. I've used the more buttons module to provide a cancel button. If the cancel button is pressed, then the user is returned to the table page and can continue editing. However, if she clicks on save it simply displays the updated content (and not particularly nicely) and it's not easy for the user to get back to the table and continue their updates.

I was wondering if there's a simple way of returning the user to the table page after the save button? Note if the edit is performed from the more standard drupal content listing admin pages, then it should return to the content listings pages there.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a rewritten "Content: Nid" field to create the Edit link field with a [`destination`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/drupal_get_destination/7) parameter that points back to the URL of the page with the table.

The "Link path" field should look something like this:
`node/[nid]/edit?destination=path/to/table`

[image]

Comment: Thanks Adam. As it happens views automatically creates the destination parameter so I don't need to use the rewrite approach. It turns out the behaviour is caused by a bug (I think) in the module More Buttons. Disable it and the save works as I want. I have raised the issue (see https://drupal.org/node/1416844#comment-8393077) but it looks like More Buttons is no longer maintained unfortunately.